# dont refresh the page when you submit the form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

hii guys im new to web programing and im creating a website
in this website i want to add a contact us form in the footer of the page like this

```
<form action="footer_contactus1.php" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-grope col-lg-4">
      <label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Name</label><br>
      <input name="cuname" type="text" class="form-cotrol">
    </div>
    <div class="form-grope col-lg-4">
      <label><samp class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></samp>Email</label><br>
      <input name="cuemail" type="email" class="form-cotrol">
    </div>
    <div class="form-grope col-lg-4">
      <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i>Phone Number</label><br>
      <input name="cutele" type="tel" class="form-cotrol">
    </div>

    <div class="form-grope col-lg-12">
    <br>
      <label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>Message</label><br>
      <textarea name="cumessage" class="form-cotrol" rows="6" style="width: 100%;" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-grope col-lg-12">
    <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and when i click the submit button i want the php file to get executed so the inputs got inserted into the database
the php file

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mywsite_db', 'root', '');

$req = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO message (id_message,nom,email,tele,message)
VALUES(null,?,?,?,?)');
$req->execute(array($_POST['cuname'],$_POST['cuemail'],$_POST['cutele'],$_POST['cumessage']));

header('Location: HomePage.php');

?>
```

i wanted this form to get submited without refreshing the page by ajax
i tried different tutorials and nothing worked can you plzz gives me the correct ajax script for my form so i can submit it to the php file and insert the data on the database then a message (alert) pop up telling me that the data has been inderted without refreshing the page plzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="footer_contactus1.php" method="post" id="myForm1">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#myForm1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('The data has been inserted');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```